# Problem sending mails with multiple threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, smtp

i have a problem with the code below. the mail is sent with a duplicate content of the string s. why is this happening?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<String> liste = new List<String>();
        liste.Add("1");
        liste.Add("2");
        liste.Add("3");
        liste.Add("4");
        liste.Add("5");
        liste.Add("6");

        foreach(string s in liste)
            new Thread(x => SendMail(s)).Start();
    }

    static void SendMail(string s)
    {
        MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage("from", "to");
        mailMsg.Body = s;
        mailMsg.Subject = s;

        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("mySMTP");

        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

        smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myUse", "myPass");
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;

        try
        {
            smtpClient.Send(mailMsg);
        }
        catch (SmtpException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which version of .Net are you using?

Comment: Do you mean that for each mail message body, the value of the string appears twice? i.e. "11", "22", "33" etc. in the body?

Comment: What happens when you replace your `foreach` loop with just `liste.AsParallel().ForAll(SendMail);`?

Comment: @Peter: no I mean that I receive mails with the same message header and body, e.g. header of first received mail: 1, header of second received mail: 1.

@Nick: yes that works. but why am is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using .Net 4.0 you can use a few new constructs available here, you can replace this:

```
foreach(string s in liste)
  new Thread(x => SendMail(s)).Start();
```

With a [`Parallel.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx):

```
Parallel.ForEach(liste, SendMail);
```

Or, inappropriate for the case but works the [`.ForAll()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383744.aspx) extension:

```
liste.AsParallel().ForAll(SendMail);
```

Someone correct me here, but what I *think* is happening is that if a Thread takes *any* time to start up it's referencing a `s` from the foreach that doesn't belong to it.  The thread it passing a the value of `s` into SendMain, *but* it's *getting* that value when it's ready for it...and that may be after the `foreach` loop has already moved on, meaning that the string that `s` points to has changed.

For example: If 2 threads start, one slow and one fast...the first slow one might get an `s` from a later `foreach()` iteration, and the faster one may get the correct `s` for the current loop.  That means 2 threads got the *same* `s` reference, and the first thread copied the wrong value to pass into `SendMail()`.